# dpkg does not remove file that belonged to previous version of package

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I have a manually built Debian package from where I removed one file (let's say `/etc/profile.de/mypackage.sh`) in the most recent version because it was moved to a different package.

When I manually install that package using `dpkg -i mypackage.deb` the file does neither get deleted from the file system nor from dpkg's database.

These are the contents of the current deb:

```
$ dpkg -c mypackage.deb 
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2017-08-01 14:36 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2017-08-01 14:36 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2017-08-01 14:36 ./usr/lib/
-rwxr-xr-x root/root    954376 2017-08-01 14:36 ./usr/lib/mylib.so
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2017-08-01 14:36 ./etc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2017-08-01 14:36 ./etc/ld.so.conf.d/
-rw-r--r-- root/root        29 2017-08-01 14:36 ./etc/ld.so.conf.d/mypackage.conf
```

When I ask for the currently installed from that package, I get:

```
$ dpkg-query -L mypackage

/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/mylib.so
/etc
/etc/ld.so.conf.d
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/mypackage.conf
/etc/profile.d/mypackage.sh
```

Any ideas on how to fix that?

I cannot purge the package completely as too many other packages depend on it.

Comment: run autoclean or autoremove

Comment: @saviour123 no, both commands do no nothing